# How to constantly take pictures in Android Camera2?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android project where I have to repeatedly take photos and process them with a facial recognition API. I realize that I have to use camera2's methods (either setRepeatingRequest or setRepeatingBurst), but these methods only take a photo once every 5 seconds or so. I was wondering how I would change this to take a picture at least twice every second without lag. Is this even possible? If not, what would you recommend I use to do this?

Comment: By the way, please let me know if you need to see the code to understand what I'm talking about!

Comment: *twice every second without lag*? Where do you plan to get the processor time to do any facial recognition if you tie up 100% of the CPU and RAM taking pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            try (Image image = reader.acquireNextImage()) {
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                if (planes.length > 0) {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(data);
                    mCallback.onPictureTaken(data);
                }
            }
        }

    };
```

This may help you,here is the use of `Camera2`.

https://github.com/google/cameraview
https://github.com/google/cameraview/blob/master/library/src/main/api21/com/google/android/cameraview/Camera2.java